# Jquery get the pervious selected value in listbox

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a list box with 10 elements. now the element 5 is selected. If i change the value to 8 then i need to get both 5 and 8.

i.e I need the currently selected item and previous selected item.

Is there any possibility in Jquery. Please do the needful. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// on load
$("#mySelect").data("previous-value", $("#mySelect").val());

// on change
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
    var previousValue = $(this).data("previous-value");

    // do things with the previous value

    // update previous value
    $(this).data("previous-value", $(this).val());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/YGJG3/)

Comment: I have my change function with class name as $(".cls").change(function() { } Here i have multiple list box with same name. While alert the variable previousValue  it returns as 'Undefined'. Is there any need to change the code? I am new to jquery. Please help. Thanks

Comment: If you have a multiple select box you can just hold CTRL and click the items to select more than one.