# Jquery get previous value in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I get the script for selecting the previous selected value in list box from  [Jquery get the pervious selected value in listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326494/jquery-get-the-pervious-selected-value-in-listbox)

It is fine for the individual select boxes.

I have multiple select boxes. I wrote the change event with the class name. It returns undefined. Please refer this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/uW2ND/1/

How can i get the previous selected value of the each selected list box with this.

Comment: it returns undefined because it is undefined. You don't have any "data" attributes on elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to include the code that actually sets the value of the jQuery-data to the previous value!

Check out this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/uW2ND/2/

Answer (score 3):

This fiddle illustrates the proper way to persist the previous value. More specifically, it stores each select box's previous value in its related data() container. The first time around it would not alert anything, since no previous value is set.

http://jsfiddle.net/KxEKd/1/

Comment: you also have to store default value as data in previous-value in docuemnt ready state.so taht first time u got prev value